# Ubuntu 16.04 Steam only runs from terminal

Tags: command-line, games, steam

After a botched upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 I had to wipe my system and start all over. This time I decided to go with a much less CPU intensive desktop environment and installed Lubuntu 16.04-1.

My problem: when I run Steam from the menu shortcut it acts like it is doing nothing. However it does show up in the task manager. If I just type `steam` in the terminal I get the following.

```
michael@michael-HP-Pavilion-dm1-Notebook-PC:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
/bin/bash: /home/michael/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
awk: /home/michael/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1468023329)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Then nothing happens including steam doesn't show up in the task manager. Now I did find the command.

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

This does run Steam but it is not a real solution in my eyes. How can I fix it?

Comment: If this issue isn't already reported on the [Steam-for-Linux github,](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues) then it may be worth reporting it.

Comment: We have reasons to believe your question is more generally applicable to Ubuntu and its official flavors, so I am going to change Lubuntu back to Ubuntu in the title.

Comment: Ok as long as Lubuntu users know that It was a Lubuntu user that had the problem. Thank you

Comment: @MichaelScholler Yeah, they would. I kept the Lubuntu part in the body of the post intact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have a command (`LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam`) to launch it correctly, modify the `.desktop` file to fix the menu icon so that clicking it runs that command. Do:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
```

and then type `ls` to find the `.desktop` file for Steam. Here I'm assuming it's called `steam.desktop`, so check that, and correct the commands below if necessary. Make a backup copy

```
sudo cp steam.desktop steam-bak
```

(restore the backup if needed by doing `mv steam-bak steam.desktop`) edit the original file:

```
sudo nano steam.desktop
```

find the first line that starts `Exec=` (you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to search in nano) and edit the line so it says:

```
Exec=bash -c "LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam"
```

Save the file and exit (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>)

Now click the steam icon in the menu to launch

Note to others: if the command `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam` does not work for you, try changing `DISPLAY=:0` to match your environment. First do `echo $DISPLAY` and if the output is `:0.0`, then instead of `DISPLAY=:0` in the steam launch command, put `DISPLAY=:0.0`

---

Another possible fix: check **System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers** and enable the latest proprietary drivers (suggestion from a comment on another post that apparently worked for the OP of that post)

---

The errors are caused by outdated drivers and libraries bundled with Steam. This can be fixed by disabling them, so that Steam uses system files instead (this is why setting `LD_PRELOAD` works). You could disable the file(s) throwing errors by renaming them:

```
mv /home/$USER/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5{,.disabled}
```

(there may be several libraries you need to do this to, and you may need to repeat after any updates/resyncing) In any case, it's not a problem with your system, but with Steam.

For comprehensive information see:
[Epic Arch wiki post on troubleshooting Steam](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Game-specific_troubleshooting)

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. Since I have this started do you see anything else that should be fixed? I see those errors and missing drivers ... do you think this is a problem and /or is it something i should fix or be worried about?

Comment: ah yes... here's the fix to get rid of those errors on [Arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183659) which may work. The drivers are outdated and system ones need to be used instead. Presumably that is why setting LD_PRELOAD fixes the problem. I will edit my answer...

Comment: You are on a roll. I wish I would of tried this a week ago.