# Steam won't work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, games, steam

Whenever I install steam it won't run, nothing happens when opened. I had Lubuntu but couldn't get steam working to save my life, so I installed Ubuntu that has the exact same problem....

I've been looking all over the place for answers. The most common answer i've found and tried is:

```
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1{,.disable}
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libs
```

or along those lines (a few variations). However whenever I do this and try to run steam it says: Updating Steam, and reinstalls what I've just removed and then does nothing again. And stopping the update doesn't seem to help.

Comment: see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/812040/lubuntu-16-04-steam-only-runs-from-terminal/) and the answer... if it works, your question can be closed as a duplicate of that one :)

Comment: using:
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam

made steam run.  Thank you!. at least i can run it.  but this has to be entered in before every use, editing the steam.desktop file like the solution said did not work for me

Comment: hmm are you sure you edited it exactly like that? what happens when you click the launcher after editing? could you please do `cat /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop` and [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) the output and link to it here ?

Comment: Please elaborate us on `reinstall what I've just removed` part. Steam doesn't install system component what you can remove using apt-get.

Comment: Also let us see the content in `~/Steam/bootstrap_log.txt`. You can edit your question to include those lines. If it is too big, only include the last section. The sections are separated with line breaks

Comment: The answers in the linked question include instructions how to add the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to the desktop starter of Steam.