# No .steam folder when installing Steam

Tags: steam

When I install Steam it tells me that it couldn't set up Steam data. I looked that up and the solutions that I found include deleting the `.steam` folder so that it makes one from fresh. But I don't have a `.steam` folder, no matter how I install Steam (`.deb` file installation or using the terminal).

When I use the terminal to launch it, it tells me this:

```
Repairing installation, linking /home/nik/.steam/steam to /home/nik/.local/share/Steam
rm: cannot remove '/home/nik/.steam/steam': Is a directory
Setting up Steam content in /home/nik/.local/share/Steam
rm: cannot remove '/home/nik/.steam/steam': Is a directory
```

Comment: How do you know you don't have a `.steam` directory? The period at the front means that the directory is hidden, so you can see it by running `ls -a` in `~`. Did you try this?

Comment: Or, in the File Explored (Nautilus, probably), press Ctrl+H to view hidden files and folders.

Answer (score 1):

According to those command outputs, you do have a `.steam` directory, but it is hidden (because it starts with a `.`)

Use `ls -d .*` to show all hidden files or `ls -A` to show all files

The error `is a directory` is giving you a hint that you need to use the `-r` (recursive) flag to remove directories

```
rm -r .steam
```

But that is probably NOT the best way to fix your Steam issues. Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812040/lubuntu-16-04-steam-only-runs-from-terminal/812114#812114) or [read this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4l0tir/no_more_steam_broke_on_latest_update_posts_please/) for better solutions.