# Steam won't startup Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: steam

I recently installed Ubuntu (32-bit) on my older computer and tried to play some games on it with steam. Once the launcher has been installed, it wouldn't launch, but I fixed it with the help of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771032/steam-not-opening-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts). Once it launched, it started updating. Once that was done, it closed, and would never open again. When I type steam in the terminal I get this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Maybe [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/812040/lubuntu-16-04-steam-only-runs-from-terminal/) helps?

Comment: That's great. If that fixes it for you, maybe we can close thus question as duplicate of that one?

Comment: Actually it doesn't, replied a bit too quick, it started updating again but that was it, still can't open it and it still says the same thing in the terminal

Comment: Uh-oh haha... so you can't run it even with LD_PRELOAD? If it updates, it's probably breaking the `.desktop` file again. I wonder if you can stop it from updating... I'm not at my machine right now, but let us know the details and we'll try to find a fix

Comment: What video driver are you using? I've found that Steam doesn't like the open-source video driver. Also, how did you install Steam?

Comment: What is LD_PRELOAD? I'm pretty new to this so I don't know any of these names

Comment: @David - your friend   Don't really know what driver I'm using but I think this will do http://imgur.com/a/KY2mC  And installed it just using the installer from the steam site

Comment: The question I linked to has LD_PRELOAD in the command to launch steam - did you use it? What did you try exactly? What it does is tell steam where to look first for shared libraries, because otherwise it uses outdated ones. (btw this isnt my post so you need to add @Zanna so I get a ping)

Comment: Try choosing the latest proprietary video driver from AMD/ATI available in  System Settings>Software & Updates>Additional Drivers. Also, try Zanna's suggestion.

Comment: @David-yourfriend - your friend  So I looked in the additional drivers and didn't see any video card drivers, but there was an unkown inactive driver that was called microcode for amd64 processors (ore something like that). Then Tried to launch steam again, still nothing, Tried reinstalling, launched and updated steam again and still nothing, BUT when I was writing this comment steam opend out of nowhere so I guess it worked :)
And just to add before I reinstalled steam there wans't a LD_PRELOAD in the launch command, but after reinstalling there was one and it worked!!!!

Comment: @Zanna and  David - your friend THANKS FOR THE HELP!!! (ran out of characters in previous comment)

Comment: @ian glad you found a solution! I was beginning to think, a re-install would do you good.