# Steam Not Launching on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: steam

I got Ubuntu this morning, and I'm currently running it alongside Windows 10.

I got steam on Ubuntu, and every time I launch it, it blinks a few times on the side bar and disappears. after that.

Please help, I really want Steam on Ubuntu.

Comment: is this any use? http://askubuntu.com/questions/812040/ubuntu-16-04-steam-only-runs-from-terminal/

Comment: Hey @wyattcole72, can you please close this question because you found a fix?